# Visual Studio doesn't recognize boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2017, boost-asio

1. I download the last version of boost.
2. I built binaries by executing "bootstrap" and "./b23
3. I added the include directory "$(SolutionDir)lib\boost_1_75_0" and linked the binary one "$(SolutionDir)lib\boost_1_75_0\stage\lib"

Everything compiles and works fine. I have a problem that prevents me from being productive: VS is unable to recognize libraries... Here a picture:

[image]

Why intelisense unable tor ecognize the library, but is able to work?

[EDIT 1]

Here's my project layout.
[image: Project layout]

Thanks,

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1387438

Comment: I assume your file is part of a project? Intellisense doesn't always work on non-project files

Comment: @MarekR Thank you for your information. If you have a solution to make appear that intellisense doesn't recognize the class only by writing, I will take it into consideration. But rules aren't available in any cases ;).

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for your answer! Yes it is. I'm going to complete my post with my project layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by upgrading to Visual Studio 2019.

Thanks.